# C++ OpenCV equivalent for C# EmguCV Image.setValue(...) method

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv

If someone can share the code for

What is C++(OpenCV) equivalent for Image.setValue(...) method in C# EmguCV framework.
emgucv reference:
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/Index.html

for example how to code in C++ next:

```
 private static Image<Gray, Byte> FilterPlate(Image<Gray, Byte> plate)
 {
  ...
  Image<Gray, Byte> thresh = plate.ThresholdBinaryInv(new Gray(120), new Gray(255));
  using (Image<Gray, Byte> plateMask = new Image<Gray, byte>(plate.Size))
  plateMask.SetValue(255.0);
  ...
  thresh.SetValue(0, plateMask);
  }
```

especially what is C++ equivalent for next:

```
  thresh.SetValue(0, plateMask);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not use EmguCV, but as documentation said

```
 thresh.SetValue(0, plateMask);
```

> Set the element of the Array to val, using the specific mask

So, I think, you can use

> void cvSet(CvArr* arr, CvScalar value, const CvArr* mask=NULL)
>
> ```
> Sets every element of an array to a given value.
> ```

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html#set

Example:

```
cvSet(thresh, CvScalar(0), plateMask);
```